# What is a verb for "the usage of an angry tone of voice"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a term meaning *the use of an angry tone of voice without the raising or lowering of one's volume.*  Something like *yell*, but without the implication of raising one's voice.

I'm hoping for something general. Words like *snarl* and *snap* don't work in all contexts, so I'm looking for something better.

I'm looking for something that might fill this sentence: "You're ______ again, Dave." as a speaker is counseling a person with anger management issues.

Comment: What is wrong with _an angry tone of voice_?

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: @RobertCartaino: it seems out of the spirit of the whole SE thing for a moderator like yourself, without a vested -content specific- interest, to be autocratically closing questions. I think the 5 vote rule handles these situations just fine.

Comment: Also @RobertCartaino, disregarding the unilateral-closing-by-an-outsider issue, this question clearly shows effort, and specifies exactly what context he wants to use the word in. In other words, isn't this precisely the sort of single-word-request we want to **encourage**?

Comment: @martha while I agree there is a bit of context provided in the question and I have certainly seen worse, the answers demonstrate that the question is still little more than a thinly veiled game of [charades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades) that can be judged only by the asker; it's darn near a poll. How would you objectively determine which answer is correct? For example, the accepted answer is a *list of possible words*.

Comment: I very strongly disagree with this question being, once again, unilaterally closed by an outsider. @JeffAtwood: exactly what is so earth-shatteringly wrong about an answer that is a (gasp, horrors) *list of words*?

Comment: @mar well, a list of words as the accepted answer is strong evidence of an opinion poll, as specified in the text of the close reason. "we don't know what you want, try any of these on for size!" Even the best of these charades questions are still not good.

Comment: @JeffAtwood, if you don't think any of the answers are good, write a better one. If you can't, at least leave the question open so that someone else can write a better answer. I think the criteria here are very clear; the reason the answers aren't better is that it's a hard question. Is StackExchange only for the easy-to-answer fluff questions?

Comment: @mar there's no objective reality here; we are guessing as to whatever the op feels is "best" which is why the accepted answer is ... a list of guesses. Adding more guesses isn't improving the Internet for anyone. In fact the accepted answer is basically a thesaurus entry... That is not what we want English.se to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tone-of-voice words include *irate, cross, indignant, nettled, riled, heated, incensed, biting, resentful, provoked, imprecation.*  Examples: "'You're late!', she said hotly" and "'Come here,' he said crossly."

Looking specifically at verbs we have *fume, rave, grumble, chide, rebuke, chafe, fret, remonstrate, recriminate, decry*.  Examples: "'What have you done now?", she raved", "'There's none for me,' he grumbled" and "'I'm so lame", she fumed."  Also see [list of 214 words](http://www.spwickstrom.com/said/) some believe can be used in place of *said*.

Comment: I'm going through them. I like _decry_ but it's not exactly the meaning I'm looking for. _fume_ too. I'm looking for something that might fill this sentence: "You're XXX again, Dave." as a speaker is counseling a person with anger management issues.

I think _incensed_ is the closest to the emotional state I'm going for with the word. Thanks!

Comment: @DracoRo'Tor - Maybe try "You're overheating again, Dave", or "getting riled up",  or "getting [wrought-up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wrought-up)" (agitated).

Comment: Although they closed it on me, this was the post I would have gone with as my answer, since your _remonstrate_ led me to _Vilipend_ and _exectrate_ on a thesaurus website. Between the three, I think I'm as close as I can get to my goal.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be inclined to say 'Don't look at me in that tone of voice.'

Comment: I've never been looked at in a tone of voice before.

Comment: @Mahnax Oh, I'm sure you have, but didn't realise.

Answer (score 4):

*Growl*, *hiss*, and the like, as in:

> "You had better not do that," he growled.

> "Shut up," she hissed.

Comment: I thought of those, but most have a volume component. For example, a hiss is generally quieter, coming through gritted teeth or under one's breath. 

I want something where someone can <angry voice> at someone else, without the context of a particular onomatopoeia-esque sound, like snapping at someone or growling at someone.

Thanks for the ideas, though

Comment: Notice both evoke animal imagery. Dogs growl, snakes (and I suppose cats) hiss. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

To *[rant](http://www.wordnik.com/words/rant)* is "to speak in an angry or violent manner" -- not necessarily with volume.

(It's actually more chilling that way.)

Comment: I too thought of *rant* but felt that "violent" implies loudness, as do some of the other defining terms in the page you linked: uproarious, boisterous, "speak or shout at length", "talk in a noisy, excited, or declamatory manner", "loud bombastic declamation".  *Rave* may have some of the same problems.

Comment: @jwpat7 Yeah, I was surprised that _rant_ wasn't on your rather comprehensive list. I'm not sure that there's a word for "ranting at low volume."

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a single word but the phrase "His voice was seething with anger" comes to mind - but perhaps the term "seething" is too intense for your liking. Also, it has to be used in a descriptive way to make clear that it refers to one's voice.

Comment: intensity is fine. like I said to Pete, it's mainly that all the angry words seem to apply better to rope (snap), animals (growl, hiss, bark, yap), pots (seethe, fume), etc. 

Also, I don't mind if I come off a little sesquipedal by using the word.

Comment: Consider an active form like  “His voice seethed with anger” instead of  “His voice was seething with anger”

Answer (score 0):

How about this: You are short fused again, Dave.